# The uniqueness of Hermite's interpolating polynomial in the case of $n=2$ nodes

Tags: functions, polynomials, numerical-methods, interpolation

The problem is :[image]
I have tried to prove the problem using proof by contradiction. However, I got stuck. I am not sure which role the derivatives of the function $p$ and $f$ should play, or how we should use the points $x_0$ and $x_1$.

Comment: I have taken the liberty of updating your question. Most importantly, I have added key words to the title which closely reflect your question. This will help people in the future when they search for questions/answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought it would interesting to give a proof of uniqueness by contradiction.

---

Suppose there are two polynomials $p$ and $q$ of degree at most $3$ such that
$$ f(x_i) = p(x_i) = q(x_i), \quad i = 0, 1,$$
and
$$ f'(x_i) = p'(x_i) = q'(x_i), \quad i = 0, 1,$$
I claim that $r = p - q$ is the zero polynomial. It is clear that $r$ has degree at most $3$, i.e., 
$$r (x) = a x^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$$
for suitable $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$. Moreover, we have
$$ r(x_i) = p(x_i) - q(x_i) = 0, \quad i = 0, 1,$$
and
$$ r'(x_i) = p'(x_i) - q'(x_i), \quad i = 0, 1.$$
We will now show that $a=0$. This will be done by repeated application of Rolle's theorem. It can be helpful to draw a line and mark and name the points as they are discovered. By Rolle's theorem, $r'$ has at least one zero $\xi$ between $x_0$ and $x_1$. Moreover, since $r'(x_0) = r'(x_1) =0$, Rolles's theorem show that $r''$ has at least one zero between $x_0$ and $\xi$ and at least one zero between $\xi$ and $x_1$. In particular, $r''$ has at least two zeros between $x_0$ and $x_1$. By another application of Rolle's theorem, we conclude that $r'''$ has at least one zero. However, $$r'''(x) = 6a,$$ so $a=0$ as claimed. We now know that $$r(x) = bx^2 + cx + d.$$ This implies $$r'(x) = 2bx + c.$$ Since $r'$ has two distinct zeros, we have immediately $b=c=0$. This reduces $r$ to the tantalizing form $$r(x) = d.$$
Since $r$ has at least one zero, we conclude that $r=0$. It follows that $p=q$.

---

In reality, I have merely adapted the proof of the error formula, i.e.,
$$\forall x \: \exists \xi \: : \: f(x) - p(x) = \frac{f^{(4)}(\xi)}{4!}(x-x_0)^2(x-x_1)^2,$$
where $p$ is the polynomial given in the text, i.e., Hermite's interpolation polynomial of degree at most $3$. It is also possible to give a formula for $p$ directly in terms of the given values of $f$ and $f'$, but this is a subject for a separate investigation.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it seems like the polynomial has to be cubic. So, it would be given by: $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3$. So, if we know what the values of $a_0$ to $a_3$ are, we've fully specified the polynomial. The conditions given involve four conditions that translate to four equations. These equations are:

\begin{align}
a_0  +a_1 x_0 +a_2 x_0 ^2 + a_3 x_0^3 = f(x_0)\\
a_0  +a_1 x_1 +a_2 x_1 ^2 + a_3 x_1^3 = f(x_1)\\
a_1+ a_2 2x_0+a_3 3x_0^2=f'(x_0)\\
a_1+ a_2 2x_1+a_3 3x_1^2=f'(x_1)
\end{align}

Four equations in four unknowns means there is a unique solution, unless the system is under-specified.

The system becoming under-specified can only happen if one of the equations can be constructed from a linear combination of the other three. For a general system, $Au=b$, this happens if the determinant, $|A|=0$.

For your particular system, the matrix $A$ of the LHS becomes -

$$
A=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -h/2 & h^2/4 & -h^3/8 \\
    1 & h/2 & h^2/4 & h^3/8 \\
    0 & 1 & -h & 3h^2/4\\
   0 & 1 & h & 3h^2/4 \end{bmatrix}
$$

The [Determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) of this matrix turns out to be $|A| = \frac{h^4}{4}$.

This determinant can only be $0$ if $h=0$. Otherwise, the system will have one unique solution.

You might also find the  [Taylor series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) of a smooth function instructive.

Comment: but how do you know that f(x) is a polynomial ?

Comment: Where in the answer did you feel like I assumed $f(x)$ itself was a polynomial? We merely used $f(x_0), f(x_1), f'(x_0), f'(x_1)$ to approximate it *by* a polynomial. The problem is, what is the best possible polynomial we can use to approximate it.

Comment: Ahh, right. That was a typo, fixed.